# updating final List before updating arrayAdapter/listView

Tags: java, android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I am trying to update a listview after the user deleted an entry. I found I needed to use `notifyDataSetChanged()`. But to use that I need to update the arrayList first (correct?). But I can't change that because that List is declared final.

It is final because I need it in the `getView` method and otherwise Android Studio complains about not being able to access it via an inner class.

The relevant code:

```
        final List<String> arrayList = mydb.getAllAlarms();
        final List<String> timesList = mydb.getAllAlarmTimes();
        final ArrayList<Integer> arrayListID = mydb.getAllAlarmIDs();

        boolean isEmpty = false;
        if (arrayList.isEmpty()) { //default
            arrayList.add("You have no alarms");
            timesList.add("");
            isEmpty = true;
        }

        //initialise arrayadapter to show stuff in the listview
        final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, android.R.id.text1, arrayList) {
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

                TextView text1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
                TextView text2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(android.R.id.text2);
                text1.setText(arrayList.get(position));
                text2.setText(timesList.get(position));
                return convertView;
            }
        };

        final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter); //set our custom adapter to the listview

        if (!isEmpty) { //only set clicklistener if there are alarms
            //set clicklistener for items in the listview
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                //...
            });
            listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                    //first, find the corresponding database id
                    final int idToDelete = arrayListID.get(position);

                    //show dialog
                    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                            MainActivity.this);
                    alert.setTitle("Delete alarm");
                    alert.setMessage("Are you sure?");
                    alert.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            mydb.deleteAlarm(idToDelete);
                            //cancel alarm as well
                            ShowAlarm.cancelAlarmIfExists(getApplicationContext(), idToDelete);

                            dialog.dismiss();

                        }
                    });

                    //...
                    alert.show();

                    //PROBLEM LIES HERE

                    //reload listview
//                    arrayList = mydb.getAllAlarms(); //not possible because final List

                    arrayAdapter.clear();
                    arrayAdapter.addAll(arrayList);

                    arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
//                    listView.invalidateViews();
//                    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

                    return true;
                }
            });

        }
```

Comment: Copy that list to another list and use that to set adapter

Comment: You can do this `arrayAdapter.addAll(mydb.getAllAlarms());` or `arrayList.clear(); arrayList.addAll(mydb.getAllAlarms());`. There is no need to reinitialize the list in order to change it.

Comment: @Titus Ah I didn't know you don't have to edit the exact same arrayList. It seems logical, somehow the listView still doesn't update though after a `clear()` and `addAll`.

Comment: but why not making the arrayList global?

Comment: declare the arrayList  globally and try it

Comment: You need to change only the adapter or the list, the changes you make to one of them will affect them both. Once you do that, don't forget to call `arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Comment: @Opiatefuchs I just tried that, seems another elegant solution but still my `listView` only updates if I go to another activity and back (which rebuilds the whole thing of course). Maybe the problem with updating is somewhere else? I'm confused.

Comment: you have to update your adapter arraylist and not the ui list try getting all items from arraylist and then remove it

Comment: @ankitagrawal What do you mean exactly? I only have one  (global) arrayList, right? What I have now, I updated the global variable `arrayList` and then do `clear()`, `addAll(arrayList)` and `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: you can use arrayAdapter.getItem(position); to get a item from your arraylist and perform operation so that it will be reflected correctly

Comment: @ankitagrawal Hey that is smart! Indeed, changing directly the items from the arrayAdapter reflects changes immediately. No need for extra update code. This is by far the most elegant solution to me. If you make it into an answer I can accept it.

Comment: sure i will post it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `arrayAdapter.getItem(position);` to get a item from your arraylist and perform operation so that it will be reflected correctly

Comment: Sure, upvoting each other here and there is deserved ;)